# Cannot Set CORS with Blazegraph (localhost:9999, Jetty) for Access from Another Port (localhost:600, http-server)

Tags: cors, jetty, httpserver, same-origin-policy, blazegraph

I've been running [MediaWiki with Wikibase](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Installation), the [Wikidata Query Service](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/Implementation/Standalone) ([GitHub](https://github.com/wikimedia/wikidata-query-rdf)), and the [Wikidata Query Service GUI](https://github.com/wikimedia/wikidata-query-gui) on a remote Ubuntu server. I am tunneling into that server in order to access things on my local machine.

The GUI (running at localhost:8080 on the server, localhost:600 on the local machine) is attempting to contact the Query Service, specifically Blazegraph, which is running via a Jetty server (localhost:9999 on both server and local machine).

Everything works in terms of separate components (successful installations, no errors), and if a SPARQL query is entered in the Blazegraph UI or taken and copy-pasted into the browser, the correct RDF output is produced. However, if the query is run from the Wikidata Query Service GUI, it produces a `net::ERR_FAILED 200` and:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9999/bigdata/sparql' from origin 'http://localhost:600' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The Wikidata Query Service GUI is run using `npm start`, which in turn runs `http-server --cors='*'`. The Blazegraph at `localhost:9999` is run using:

```
sudo BLAZEGRAPH_OPTS="-DwikibaseConceptUri=http://localhost:400" bash /var/lib/mediawiki/extensions/wikidata-query-rdf/dist/target/service-0.3.111-SNAPSHOT/runBlazegraph.sh
```

I'm not sure exactly how to go about allowing the Wikidata Query Service GUI to access the Wikidata Query Service, so any help would be much appreciated!

UPDATE 1: It might be helpful to say that this is with Jetty 9?

Comment: Chrome has tons of special rules for domain names that are IP addresses, single label domains, and reserved hostnames such as `"test"` or `"localhost"`, etc. These do not work normally for TLS/SSL, SameSite, CORs, Preflight requests, etc. Avoid using any of these while you are testing, use a fully qualified hostname when you can, otherwise you'll be surprised by these rules.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not just Chrome, and it's the same error in all browsers I've tried (IE, Microsoft Edge, Firefox, Opera). I believe this an issue with the Maven build, which removes things (like servlets) as soon as `maven install` is run-- even if servlets appears in the `pom.xml`.

Comment: Try using a real hostname (not localhost or IP) and see if the results change.  If the results change, then you know it's the localhost causing the problems.

Comment: Unfortunately due to system limitations (I don't own the server), I couldn't set up a real host name. However, I finally got it to work by using a proxy Apache2 server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out, by adding a proxy into `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`, as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:9000>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9999/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9999/
</VirtualHost>
```

This then listens for the call from localhost:8080->localhost:9000, and redirects the call to localhost:9999. I also added a bit more information to a related [Phabricator](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T308180) page.